# What is the meaning of "as having"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "as having" in English language? For example, in this fragment:

> Celebrities who have been quoted as having used something

Is this an idiom or something else? I am not getting the clear meaning of this.

Comment: @user127219 'As' is being used no differently here to the way it is in many other instances with a present participle; e.g. 'John has been quoted as liking sugar', 'Mary is reported as believing in ghosts'.

Comment: Still didn't get it. May be, i need some more simple and understandable examples.Thanks

Comment: There is nothing special about _as having_. You should have a look at _as_. Can you explain what confuses you after you look it up in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction you should be looking at is not "as having" but "quoted as V-ing". Remember: "as" and "like" mean "similar to".

It might be easier to explain to put it in a complete sentence:

> Celebrities who have been quoted as having used something...

Celebrities who have been quoted as having used Widgets now regret endorsing the products.

"Who have been quoted as having used Widgets" means the celebrities have said something similar to "I have used a Widget" (proper, correct English) but maybe not those exact words. Perhaps they said: "Widgets? Yeah, I used one" or "I love my Widget!" or "Widgets are wonderful!" or "I have a Widget in every room in my house."

In WS2's examples, Mary may have said, "Of course ghosts are real!" But when we state it as an indirect quote, we might say 'Mary is reported as believing in ghosts'--similar words with the same meaning.